# Shape of passed values is (12, 4), indices imply (4, 4)

Tags: pandas, regression, valueerror

[the code to make multiple Regression Models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ynlwi.png)

I am getting following error.

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in create_block_manager_from_arrays(arrays, names, axes, consolidate)
   1773         blocks = _form_blocks(arrays, names, axes, consolidate)
-> 1774         mgr = BlockManager(blocks, axes)
   1775     except ValueError as e:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in __init__(self, blocks, axes, verify_integrity)
    913 
--> 914             self._verify_integrity()
    915 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in _verify_integrity(self)
    920             if block.shape[1:] != mgr_shape[1:]:
--> 921                 raise construction_error(tot_items, block.shape[1:], self.axes)
    922         if len(self.items) != tot_items:

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (12, 4), indices imply (4, 4)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\ASUSVI~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16768/4041741565.py in <module>
     19 
     20 
---> 21 pd.DataFrame({'Train RMSE': rmse_train,'Test RMSE': rmse_test,'Training Score':scores_train,'Test Score': scores_test},
     22              index=['Linear Regression','Decision Tree Regressor','Random Forest Regressor', 'ANN Regressor'])
     23 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    612         elif isinstance(data, dict):
    613             # GH#38939 de facto copy defaults to False only in non-dict cases
--> 614             mgr = dict_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy, typ=manager)
    615         elif isinstance(data, ma.MaskedArray):
    616             import numpy.ma.mrecords as mrecords

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in dict_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype, typ, copy)
    462         # TODO: can we get rid of the dt64tz special case above?
    463 
--> 464     return arrays_to_mgr(
    465         arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype, typ=typ, consolidate=copy
    466     )

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in arrays_to_mgr(arrays, arr_names, index, columns, dtype, verify_integrity, typ, consolidate)
    133 
    134     if typ == "block":
--> 135         return create_block_manager_from_arrays(
    136             arrays, arr_names, axes, consolidate=consolidate
    137         )

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in create_block_manager_from_arrays(arrays, names, axes, consolidate)
   1774         mgr = BlockManager(blocks, axes)
   1775     except ValueError as e:
-> 1776         raise construction_error(len(arrays), arrays[0].shape, axes, e)
   1777     if consolidate:
   1778         mgr._consolidate_inplace()

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (12, 4), indices imply (4, 4)
```

please help!!!

Comment: It looks like your data has 12 rows in 4 columns, but you're trying to set the index for 4 rows.  Is it possible you meant to say `columns=['Linear Regression...` instead of `index`?

Comment: Agreed with @Tim although here you already pass column names with the dictionary keys, read again the documentation of the `DataFrame` constructor, check the format of your input and ensure you are passing the correct parameters.

Answer (score -1):

well well well...it looks like the sanswer was very simple. Just added .values.ravel() to y_train and it solved the problem.

for eg: -
i.fit(X-train,y_train.values.ravel())

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).